# How to serialize multiple sortable items and subitems in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a solution from [Sortable items and subitems in list on jQuery ui sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558323/sortable-items-and-subitems-in-list-on-jquery-ui-sortable) and everything sorts like it should, the only thing I don't understand how to do is serialize them so I could modify the database accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/5zwgx45q/

I don't know jQuery or JavaScript at all so this is all a jungle for me.

I'm using the following code to achieve what I want elsewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data;

    // Sort the parents
    $(".sortProducts").sortable({
        containment: "document"
        , group: 'serialization'
        , items: "> div"
        , handle: ".move"
        , tolerance: "pointer"
        , cursor: "move"
        , opacity: 0.5
        , revert: 300
        , placeholder: "productPlaceholder"
        , start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
        }
        , stop: function(event, ui) {
            data = $(".sortProducts").sortable("toArray", {
                attribute: 'data-id'
            });
        }

    });

    $("#saveOrder").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process/sortMenu.php?action=products'
            , type: 'POST'
            , dataType: 'json'
            , data: {
                newOrder: JSON.stringify(data)
            },

            success: function(output) {
                alert('Menu order changed successfully!');
            },

            error: function(output) {
                alert($(output['responseText']).text());
            }
        });
    });
})
```

It serializes everything

```
data = $(".sortProducts").sortable("toArray", {attribute: 'data-id'});
```

And I can apply the changes to the database. The difference here is that I have two groups of sortables (parent and children) so I don't know how to get the serialization to work for both and how to work with it.

The children could be be moved between parents and I need to be able to reflect that in the database. So I somehow need to know which child belongs to what parent.

The data is stored in the database just like a forum is.

```
ID | MenuID | Name | Position
-----------------------------
1  |   0    | Nme1 |    1
2  |   1    | Nme2 |    2
3  |   1    | Nme3 |    3
4  |   0    | Nme4 |    4
```

If MenuID is 0 it is a parent. If MenuID is 1, then it's parent is the item with the ID = 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize them"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to make more sense

Comment: Please add fiddle like http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/c1xunz44/1/

Comment: Did that: https://jsfiddle.net/5zwgx45q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function getSortableList(className){
  var sortables = $(className);
  var myArray = new Array();
  sortables.each(function() {
    myArray = myArray.concat($(this).sortable('toArray'));
  })
  // Show length of array
  alert(myArray.length);
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/bgLb67wo/2/)

**Edit**

For converting items according to your database table you can use code below:

```
function createRecordsFromSortableList() {
  var sortables = $(".menuItems");
  var records = [];

  sortables.each(function() {
    var currentParent = this;
    var myRecord = new record($(this).attr("id"), "0", $(this).closest(".menuGroup").find('h2').text());
    records.push(myRecord);
    $(this).find('.menuItem').each(function() {
      var myRecord = new record($(this).attr("id"), $(currentParent).attr("id"),$.trim($(this).text().replace(/[\t\n]+/g,' ')));
      records.push(myRecord);
    });

  });
  alert("Please see records in console.");
  console.log(records);
}

function record(id, menuId, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.menuId = menuId;
  this.name = name;
}
```

[**Online demo (get records from sortable list)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/pmwe784f/3/)

Comment: That isn't exactly what I need. I need to be able to recreate all the moved items in the database so if a child from one parent is moved to another parent, I would be able to do that in the database.

Comment: @ezw I added edit part to my answer for converting data to DB. Please see it again.

Comment: That is very close, for the children I need to somehow have the parent's ID available. https://jsfiddle.net/k8x7om75/

Comment: I was able to figure it out. (See the jsfiddle in above comment). I'm not sure if that is the most efficient way to come across it) but I got the PHP to convert that array to a usable array. Thank you